# How to calculate the sum of rows that have with the same id?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create a function that returns the final gain of a product. My problem is that for every PRODUCT_ID that takes more than 10 days to be processed I have to add (days * 0.0001) to the product's price. Many ORDER_ID'S have different PRODUCT_ID. I can't think of a way to do that in the same function.Where do I have to add the multiplication? The database schema is like this

[image]

I tried double loop and I tried SUM but non of these worked.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_gain(orderID NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
  AS
    total_price   NUMBER;
    total_cost    NUMBER;
    gain    NUMBER;

    Cursor cur1 IS
    SELECT SUM(PRICE) AS "Total PRICE"
    FROM ORDERS
    WHERE ORDER_ID=orderID;
    Cursor cur2 IS
    SELECT SUM(COST) AS "Total COST"
    FROM ORDERS
    WHERE ORDER_ID=orderID;

BEGIN
   OPEN cur1;
   FETCH cur1 INTO total_price;
   CLOSE cur1;
   OPEN cur2;
   FETCH cur2 INTO total_cost;
   CLOSE cur2;
   gain := total_price - total_cost;
   RETURN gain;

END;
```

Comment: please post a [mcve] including table definitions and example data and expected output.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use below approach to construct your query. I believe you won't need any function for this operation

```
SELECT
  ORDER_ID,
  ...
  CASE WHEN DAYS_TO_PROCESS > 10 THEN
     PRICE + DAYS_TO_PROCESS * 0.0001 
  ELSE
     PRICE
  END AS PRICE
FROM table1
WHERE ...
```

---

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. please provide more details.

Here is Function Example For updating product price

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UpdatePrice(orderID NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
  AS
    total_price   NUMBER;
    total_cost    NUMBER;
    gain    NUMBER;
BEGIN
  UPDATE table1 
  SET PRICE = 
    CASE WHEN DAYS_TO_PROCESS > 10 THEN
       PRICE + DAYS_TO_PROCESS * 0.0001 
    ELSE
       PRICE
    END
  WHERE ORDER_ID = p_ORDER_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks!It has to be a function as my professor said.